# NetworkX read_shp works on Python 2.7 but not on Python 3?

Tags: python-2.7, django, python-3, networkx

I was trying to implement the same code in Python 2.7 and Python 3.0 opening the same file from the same directory using NetworkX's read_shp function.

One, using Python 2.7 IDE and the other is using Virtualenv Python 3.0 in Django.

**Python 2.7**

```
import fiona
import networkx as nx

features = fiona.open("/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/files/test/test.shp")

print len(features)
#for feat in features:
    #print feat['geometry']

G = nx.read_shp('/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/files/test/test.shp')
print len(G.nodes())
print G.nodes()

print len(G.edges())
print G.edges()
```

**Python 3.0 Django**

```
def view_network(request):
directory  = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'files/test/test.shp')

#Open shapefile
shp = fiona.open(directory)

if shp is None:
    print('Could not open %s' % (directory))
else:
    print('Opened %s' % (directory))

    featureCount = len(shp)
    print("Number of features in %s: %d" % (os.path.basename(directory), featureCount))

    G = nx.read_shp(directory)

    print("Number of nodes %d" % G.nodes())
    print("Number of edges %d" % G.edges())

    return render(request, 'plexus/analysis.html')
```

Python 2.7 would read it and output the corresponding nodes and edges. But 3.0 would not, instead this error shows up:

> Internal Server Error: /network/view/
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 41, in inner
>   response = get_response(request)   File "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 187, in _get_response
>   response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 185, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/network/views.py", line 242,
>   in view_network
>       G = nx.read_shp(directory)   File "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/nx_shp.py",
>   line 71, in read_shp
>       for f in lyr:
>
> TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'Layer'